# Pushing Git repo issues

Tags: git, github, github-pages

[image]

So I keep getting this error when I try to push existing changes onto my github repo. This started after I created a README.md file after I noticed my repo did not have one on the github repo. Does this usually happen? If so whats the best way to fix this. I tried to delete the readme file but I definitely bugged something.

Comment: Would you be able to do a 'git pull' and then fix your code to resolve any potential merge conflicts and then push it? That usually resolves this issue.

Comment: I tried to pull it gives me a fatal error: couldnt find remote ref master

Comment: You branch is called main, not master - so that’s expected

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run: `git pull origin main`

Then run: `git push origin main`

Comment: it says fatal: couldnt find remote ref master when i do the pull

Comment: @Samee_code I edit my answer, check if it is useful

Comment: Would my url be the one I use for the github Pages? Or would it just be my repo name?

Comment: Your repo link in pic is : https://github.com/samee-ansari/excursion.git

Comment: It said remote origin already exists. And as I proceed to the next steps get the same errors. How does adding a README.md file after a project was commited cause such an error

Comment: use `main` instead `master` and check again: `git pull origin main` and `git push origin main`

Comment: I think it is because of the different structure of the code that you are committing

Comment: Good, you can accept my answer for help others that have your problem